# getting document.getElementById("range3").value in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, input, var

i just want to get document.getElementById("range3").value in a variable but my code alerts just "undefined" i don't understand why.

HTML:

```
<input name="zahl3" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" 
onchange="showValue3(this.value); rechnung()" />
<span id="range3" value="7">0</span>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
   function showValue3(newValue) {
      document.getElementById("range3").innerHTML=newValue;
   }

   function rechnung(){
      var x = 0;
      x = document.getElementById("range3").value;
      alert(x);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `.value` only works for input elements. Use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` here.

Answer (score 2):

`span` elements don't have a `value` (that's only form inputs and such), they have `innerHTML` or `innerText` (and `childNodes`). So:

```
function rechnung()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("range3").innerHTML;
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After hours of researching i finally did it.